# how to access redmine which works on a specific port?

Tags: ip, network-shares, ruby-on-rails, redmine

when I access Localhost a file management is installed there, Also I have installed redmine on localhost:3000, we have a network and people from other computers can access the domainname of this computer but they cannot access domainname:3000,therefore, they cannot access redmine, I was wondering what I can do for them to access redmine as well?

I should enter

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -p 3000 -e production
```

for the redmine to work on port 3000

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that seemed 3000 port was busy, When running, I changed the port to `-p 33` and also I used `-b x.x.x.x` which is the ip address now redmine is accessible to public, hope it can help somebody for their future, moreover I found out that you can use host name instead of ip after `-b`

Comment: In my case, using -b x.x.x.x helped me (x.x.x.x is local ip of your server) for access to redmine from other pc in our local network. thanks